# Как переопределить поле Django admin inlines

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

```
    class Post(models.Model):
        post_author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Автор", )
        post_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False, db_index=True, unique=True,
                             default="",verbose_name='Название поста')      
    class Comment(models.Model):
        comment_post = models.ForeignKey(Post,blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Пост',related_name='com' )
        comment_text = models.TextField(blank=False, verbose_name='Текст комментария')
        comment_nik = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="автор",)
```

Как к comment_nik привязать request.user

```
    class PostInline(admin.StackedInline):
        model = Comment
        fields = ['comment_nik','comment_text']
        readonly_fields = ['comment_nik', ]  # нельзя изменить поле
        extra = 2

    class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    --..--
    inlines = [PostInline,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Что значит привязать? Вы хотите в comment_nik хранить имя пользователя который создал комментарий?
У Вас comment_nik это ForeignKey на модель User. Это Ваша модель или из django.contrib.auth.models?

Comment: User это модель из django.contrib.auth.models, да. 
к модели Post я привязал вот так:
       '
     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        # при сохранении добавляем модель автора в поле post_author, если он пустой
        user = request.user
        if not instance.post_author:
            instance.post_author = user
        instance.save()
        if not instance.com:
            instance.com = user
        return instance
'
как также привязать к Inline

Comment: Код оформите, имейте уважение.